# Android studio 2.2 running app in 2 genymotion emulators simoultaniously

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion, android-studio-2.2

I want to run my app in two different emulators. When I run the app for the first time I can choose the device, but when I try to run the app in the second emulator, it doesn't show up the window to select the device, so simply it runs in the first emulator again.
My solution for now is: run the app in one emulator then close it, run the app in the second emulator, and then open the first emulator :|
How could I configure this to have it as before the upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

from edit config disable use the same device
and when you run and 2 emulator  is running you click shift and select all of them

[image]

after you run again make sure to click stop to go out of instant run.

then don't check `using same selection for future launches` 
and select by shift button your two emulators as the following image.

[image]